# Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022 strings.platformnotsupported_datasqlclient

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Hello i have an issue when my application is running after installing using [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects). When i try to connect to the database throw an Exception in runtime **strings.platformnotsupported_datasqlclient**

I am under windows 10, using net 6 to develope the application in WindowsForm using Entity Framework.

If i publish the application into a folder i do not have the exception, my program runs. But i need an installer.

Exception:

```
    Consulte el final de este mensaje para obtener más detalles sobre cómo invocar a la depuración 
Just-In-Time (JIT) en lugar de a este cuadro de diálogo.

************** Texto de la excepción **************
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.<>c.<get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled>b__7_0(String cs)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.GenerateCacheKey(Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.CountAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at WinFormsAppDailyPayments.Services.UserServices.UserLogin(String alias, String password) in C:\Users\egomez\source\repos\WinFormsAppDailyPaymetns\WinFormsAppDailyPaymetns\Services\UserServices.cs:line 13
   at WinFormsAppDailyPayments.Forms.LoginForm.buttonLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\egomez\source\repos\WinFormsAppDailyPaymetns\WinFormsAppDailyPaymetns\Forms\LoginForm.cs:line 170
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0(Object state)


************** Ensamblados cargados **************
System.Private.CoreLib
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Private.CoreLib.dll
----------------------------------------
WinFormsAppDailyPayments
    Versión del ensamblado: 1.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 1.0.0.0
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/WinFormsAppDailyPayments.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Threading
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Threading.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.2.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.60101
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App/6.0.13/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.Primitives
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.Primitives
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.2.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.60101
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App/6.0.13/System.Windows.Forms.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.InteropServices
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing.Primitives
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Drawing.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Collections.Specialized
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Collections.Specialized.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Diagnostics.TraceSource
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Collections
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Collections.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing.Common
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App/6.0.13/System.Drawing.Common.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Win32.Primitives
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.Thread
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Threading.Thread.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.60101
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App/6.0.13/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics.Vectors
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.ComponentModel.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Resources.Extensions
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App/6.0.13/System.Resources.Extensions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Memory
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Memory.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.2.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.60101
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App/6.0.13/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ObjectModel
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.ObjectModel.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Linq
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App/6.0.13/Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Collections.NonGeneric
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Collections.Concurrent
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Linq.Expressions
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Linq.Expressions.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.2.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.222.58006
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Linq.Queryable
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Linq.Queryable.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Collections.Immutable
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Collections.Immutable.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.22.51805
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Diagnostics.Tracing
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.22.51805
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.22.51805
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.2.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.222.58006
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.22.51805
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.ThreadPool
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Reflection.Primitives
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    Versión del ensamblado: 0.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Private.CoreLib.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App/6.0.13/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.2.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.222.58006
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Private.Uri
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Private.Uri.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.ReaderWriter
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Private.Xml
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Private.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Net.WebClient
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Net.WebClient.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Text.Encoding.Extensions
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.2.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.222.58006
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.Common
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Data.Common.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions.Local
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Transactions.Local.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.22.51805
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Options
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.22.51805
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Text.Json
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Text.Json.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.22.51805
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.22.51805
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives
    Versión del ensamblado: 7.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 7.0.22.51805
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ComponentModel.Annotations
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Net.Primitives
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Net.Primitives.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Net.NetworkInformation
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
    Versión del ensamblado: 5.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 5.0.0.0
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Grupo%20Total%2099/Pagos%20Diarios/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Loader
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Runtime.Loader.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.2.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.60101
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App/6.0.13/es/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Reflection.Metadata
    Versión del ensamblado: 6.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 6.0.1322.58009
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll
----------------------------------------

************** Depuración JIT **************
```

My Connectio string is taking as:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sql"].ConnectionString;
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            }
            catch
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(string.Empty);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just a wild stab in the dark here, but if you use the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package rather than `System.Data.SqlClient`, does the problem persist? Note that switching to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` is not completely seamless (for starters, it will start to want to use encryption by default, meaning you have to add `encrypt=false` to your connection strings if you can't configure that), but it's the way forward for .NET 6+ applications in any case.

Comment: i do not use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient niether System.Data.SqlClient package i am only ussging this packages Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools all in version 7.0.2, i think the problem is the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022 who creates the isntaller, the installer adds the dll Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll in folder application, but if i use publish as folder or clickonce the application runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem it seems to be a red herring of sorts.

My project setup:

```
Visual studio 2022
.NET 6
EF Core 6.0.11
Winforms
Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022
```

When the application is installed from the MSI produced by the Setup project from Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects, I got the following error when trying to run the app in the event viewer:

```
Application: ApplicationName.exe
CoreCLR Version: 6.0.1322.58009
.NET Version: 6.0.13
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.<>c.<get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled>b__7_0(String cs) etc…..
```

I noticed that the installation folder was missing the file “`ApplicationName.deps.json`” copying this to installation folder removed the error and the app worked.
The `deps.json` file contains metadata about the location and compilation of referenced assemblies, which explains why it’s throwing up the error shown above.

To get the installer working correctly you can go in to the file system of your Setup Project in Visual Studio and explicitly add the `deps.json` file in to the Application Folder. When you rebuild the Setup Project and install the issue should be resolved.

[image: Setup Project file directory]